# How do I extract structured data from CSV dump in php

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

I am experimenting with loading CSV in PHP.

I have a CSV file, with 3 columns, simple values.

I have managed to be able to loop through each line, and output each value, but I need to grab data conditionally based on unique values and based on a certain position in the row.

For example, for each unique value in column a, I need to generate an array of data objects based on the value of column b, using column c as a conditional for one of the values.

My CSV:

```
1   123 0
1   124 0
1   125 0
1   126 0
1   127 0
1   128 0
1   129 0
1   130 1
1   131 1
1   132 1
1   133 1
1   134 1
1   135 1
2   123 0
2   124 0
2   125 0
2   126 1
2   127 1
2   128 1
2   129 1
2   130 1
2   131 1
2   132 1
2   133 1
2   134 1
2   135 1
3   256 0
3   456 0
3   321 0
3   489 0
3   965 0
3   652 1
3   741 1
```

Code I am using to interrogate:

```
<?php
$stack = array();
if (($han = fopen("sample.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($han, 50, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        array_push($stack, $data); //push each arr1 into arr2(stack)
    }
    fclose($han);
}
sort($stack); //sort arr2
$newarray = array();
foreach($stack as $val){
$lineid = $val[0];
$segmentid = $val[1];
$action = $val[2];
$newarray[$lineid][$segmentid] = $action;
}
print_r($newarray);
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [123] => 0
            [124] => 0
            [125] => 0
            [126] => 0
            [127] => 0
            [128] => 0
            [129] => 0
            [130] => 1
            [131] => 1
            [132] => 1
            [133] => 1
            [134] => 1
            [135] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [123] => 0
            [124] => 0
            [125] => 0
            [126] => 1
            [127] => 1
            [128] => 1
            [129] => 1
            [130] => 1
            [131] => 1
            [132] => 1
            [133] => 1
            [134] => 1
            [135] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [256] => 0
            [321] => 0
            [456] => 0
            [489] => 0
            [652] => 1
            [741] => 1
            [965] => 0
        )

)
```

psuedocode for what I am wanting to achieve

```
for each unique column_a value {
grab all column_b's within this unique column_a and for each
    $column_b_object = new stdClass;
    $column_b_object->id = $column_b_value;
      if (column_c_value = "0") {
        $column_b_object->zero = "no";
      }
    $column_bs[] = $column_b_object;
    execute something, reset, move to next unique column_a
}
```

***EDIT SOLUTION:***

```
<?php
$stack = array();
if (($han = fopen("sample.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($han, 50, ",")) !== FALSE) {
array_push($stack, $data); //push each arr1 into arr2(stack)
}
fclose($han);
}
sort($stack); //sort arr2
$newarray = array();
foreach($stack as $val){
$lineid = $val[0]; $segmentid = $val[1]; $action = $val[2];
$newarray[$lineid][$segmentid] = $action;
}
foreach($newarray as $value) {
foreach($value as $key => $value2){
echo $key . " | " . $value2 . "<br />";
}
echo "STOP";
}
?>
```

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that if you can build the PHP code to slurp in the csv file and spit it out again, as well as write out pseudo-code for the later stages, you can build the PHP to do those later stages yourself.

Comment: Not at all. Basic looping through arrays I am fine with, but here I need to loop through an unknown number of rows, containing an unknown number of column a values. 1, 2 and 3 are samples, it could just as easily be 1223445, 547864 , 4564876 and 34908390480. So I can't iterate, I need to somehow pull out all unique values, then iterate. That's what I am having trouble with and why I am asking the question. I'm looking at array_unique etc, but I need something that only looks at a specific value, and not the entire array. I'm getting there but very slowly.

Comment: `foreach()` loops are designed for that. They'll loop over all array elements, regardless of how many/few there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your loop logic. If you still gonna iterate through every single "b" element why do you have to define the uniqueness of your "a" element? Anyway, maybe it is just me, but if you still want to do it the way your psuedo is you can:
1. Convert line from your csv into array1
2. Store that array1 into another array2
3. Sort arraty2
4. Loop through array2 and keep track of any changes in the first element (element a)

```
$i=0;
$stack = array();
if (($han = fopen("3col.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($han, 50, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        array_push($stack, $data); //push each arr1 into arr2(stack)
        $i++;
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p>";
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "|";
        }
        echo "</p>";
    }
    fclose($han);
}

sort($stack); //sort arr2

foreach($stack as $key => $arr2){
    $sameA = ($arr2[0] == $a) ? "" : "-->";
        echo $sameA;

    foreach($arr2 as $key => $val){ 
        echo $val." ";
    }
        $a = $arr2[0];
        echo "<br/>";
}
```

and the Output:

```
-->1 | 123 | 0 | 
1 | 124 | 0 | 
1 | 125 | 0 | 
1 | 126 | 0 | 
1 | 127 | 0 | 
1 | 128 | 0 | 
1 | 129 | 0 | 
1 | 130 | 1 | 
1 | 131 | 1 | 
1 | 132 | 1 | 
1 | 133 | 1 | 
1 | 134 | 1 | 
1 | 135 | 1 | 
-->2 | 123 | 0 | 
2 | 124 | 0 | 
2 | 125 | 0 | 
2 | 126 | 1 | 
2 | 127 | 1 | 
2 | 128 | 1 | 
2 | 129 | 1 | 
2 | 130 | 1 | 
2 | 131 | 1 | 
2 | 132 | 1 | 
2 | 133 | 1 | 
2 | 134 | 1 | 
2 | 135 | 1 | 
-->3 | 256 | 0 | 
3 | 321 | 0 | 
3 | 456 | 0 | 
3 | 489 | 0 | 
3 | 652 | 1 | 
3 | 741 | 1 | 
3 | 965 | 0 |
```

You can see an arrow every time you start new "a" element

Comment: Hi Nikolay - thanks for posting. Sorry, I should have been more clear. The check for the uniqueness of column b is only inside of column a. Column b should be unique within each group of unique column a's. Does that make sense? It's actually less important since the input will generally be cleansed so it is unique, the main need is on column a.

Comment: So for each batch of rows where column_A is unique, create an array or object of column_B's. This is what I am struggling with. In the above I should end up with 3 arrays, one for each column_A, and be able to do something with it.

Comment: Okay, now I have a multidimensional array containing keyed by the unique kep, so now I just need to loop on the key. Getting there.